# PHP: formatting a date from mySQL to be date only

Tags: php, datetime

I am displaying some records from mySQL from php and one of the fields I echo out is a date field but it currently prints out the time at the end to.

How can I just echo out the date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($queryresult) );

All date formatting options can be found here:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to convert it in the mySQL query using [`DATE()`:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)

```
SELECT columnname, DATE(datecolumn) FROM .....
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to do this on the DB level:

```
SELECT CAST(yourfield AS DATE) FROM .....
```

In PHP you can simply use this:

```
$parts = explode(' ', $field);
$datePart = $parts[0];
```