# extract only date without the time from MYSQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the followup procedure to display date from mysql tabe:

```
<? echo $rrow[encoded_date]; ?>
```

Now the format of encoded_date cell is: 2013-03-20 01:52:39 .

My question is how to extract only the date without the time.

Comment: Zero research : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229998/php-formatting-a-date-from-mysql-to-be-date-only?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with PHP:

```
$yourDateTime = "2013-03-20 01:52:39";
date('Y-m-d', strtotime($yourDateTime));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DATE_FORMAT()`

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dateColumn, '%Y-%m-%d') encoded_date
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/9640)

Comment: can you write the whole php code that will work with this MySQL query  ?

Comment: just echo the `alias` provided.